# Foreach in Foreach

Tags: c#, asp.net-mvc, nhibernate

Eu preciso fazer um foreach dentro de outro porém são duas tabelas
uma se chama categorias e a outra é uma galerya, preciso retornar todas as galeryas dentro de cada categoria só que o nome da categoria só aparece uma vez, eis o meu código

```
(var db = new DBContext())
        {
            //Buscando as categorias ativas
            List<Category> listCategory;
            listCategory = (from ct in db.ses.Query<Category>()
                            join g in db.ses.Query<Galery>() on ct.id equals g.idCategory
                            where ct.status == 1
                            select ct).ToList();

            //Buscando as galeryas ativas
            var list = (from g in db.ses.Query<Galery>()
                        join ct in db.ses.Query<Category>() on g.idCategory equals ct.id
                        where g.status == 1
                        && g.idCategory == idCategory
                        orderby g.id descending
                        select new IndexClass { idCategory = ct.id, title = g.title }).ToList().Take(3);

            ViewBag.listCategory = listCategory.Distinct();
            return View(list);
        }
```

ai tenho uma class genérica

```
public class IndexClass
    {
        public virtual int idCategory { get; set; }
        public virtual string nameCategory { get; set; }
        public virtual string title { get; set; }
    }
```

e essa é minha view

```
<div class="main">
<!--=====================Content======================-->
    <section class="content cont_pad1">
        <div class="container"><div class="ic">More Website Templates TemplateMonster.com - May 05, 2014!</div>
            <div class="gallery gall__1">
                <div class="row">

                    @foreach (var itemCategory in ViewBag.listCategory)
                    {
                        <div class="grid_4">
                            <h3>@itemCategory.title</h3>
                        </div>
                        <div class="clear"></div>

                        foreach (var item in Model)
                        {
                            <div class="grid_4">
                                <a href="/Content/images/uploads/galery/full1.jpg" class="gal_item">
                                    <img src="/Content/images/uploads/galery/page2_img1.jpg" alt="">
                                    <div class="gal_caption">
                                        <time datetime="2014-01-01">@item.title</time>
                                    </div>
                                    <span class="gal_magnify"></span>
                                </a>
                            </div>
                        }
                    }

                </div>
            </div>
        </div>
    </section>

</div>
```

Comment: João Vitor, você poderia remover a primeira consulta e usar um group g by ct na segunda para agrupar as galerias pela categoria.

Answer (score 1):

Amigo, não entendi o motivo do linq, vê se ajuda:

**Sua action**

```
public ActionResult Categorias()
    {
        var list = db.Category.Include("Galery").Where(ct => ct.status == 1).ToList();
        return View(list);
    }
```

**Sua View**

```
@model List<Category>
<div class="main">
  <!--=====================Content======================-->
    <section class="content cont_pad1">
    <div class="container"><div class="ic">More Website Templates TemplateMonster.com - May 05, 2014!</div>
        <div class="gallery gall__1">
            <div class="row">

                @foreach (var itemCategory in Model)
                {
                    <div class="grid_4">
                        <h3>@itemCategory.title</h3>
                    </div>
                    <div class="clear"></div>

                    foreach (var item in Model.Galery.Where(g=>g.status == 1).Take(3))
                    {
                        <div class="grid_4">
                            <a href="/Content/images/uploads/galery/full1.jpg" class="gal_item">
                                <img src="/Content/images/uploads/galery/page2_img1.jpg" alt="">
                                <div class="gal_caption">
                                    <time datetime="2014-01-01">@item.title</time>
                                </div>
                                <span class="gal_magnify"></span>
                            </a>
                        </div>
                    }
                }

            </div>
        </div>
    </div>
</section>
```

Comment: ele está usando `NHibernate` e não `Entity Framework`, então no lugar de  um `Include` você precisa fazer um `Fetch`, por exemplo: `db.ses.Query<Category>().Fetch(ct => ct.Galery)`

Answer (score 0):

Você precisa de um modelo categoria x galeria, então você realizaria um `foreach` primeiramente na categoria e depois na lista de galerias da categoria, que seria um atributo do categoria. *IEnumerable*

Outra solução seria criar uma método para retornar a lista de galerias vinculadas, porém isso não teria performance, pois a cada iteração seria um consumo ao banco.